# In activity call onStart manually

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have to do some heavy calculations in the `onCreate` method of my activity. That's why I put that stuff inside a thread that I start in the `onCreate` function.

Unfortunately some things in `onStart` do dependent on those calculations. But unfortunately `onStart` gets now called before the heavy calculation thread finishes (when the app was freshly started).

It it a good pattern to call `onStart` again manually after the calculation thread is finished?

Comment: *It it a good pattern to call onStart again manually* no, just use a callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad practice. You shouldn't manually invoke lifecycle callbacks.

Instead either:

- block the UI (perform work in `onCreate`) - another bad practice
- perform the work that you'd do in `onStart` later, i.e. after your
  work is finished.